# Testing form in React, mock function not called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a Blog component that is a parent to a BlogForm component:

This is BlogForm:

```
export const BlogForm = ({ addBlogHandle, handleBlogChange, newBlog }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={addBlogHandle}>
        <input
          placeholder="title"
          type="text"
          name="title"
          value={newBlog.title}
          onChange={handleBlogChange}
          required
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="content"
          name="content"
          value={newBlog.content}
          onChange={handleBlogChange}
          required
        />
        <br />
        <input
          placeholder="url"
          type="text"
          name="url"
          value={newBlog.url}
          onChange={handleBlogChange}
          required
        />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

addBlogHandle, handleBlogChange are event funcitons in Blog component

```
 const handleBlogChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setNewBlog((previousBlog) => ({
      ...previousBlog,
      [name]: value,
      author: user.author,
    }));
  };

  const addBlogHandle = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    blogFormRef.current.toggleVisibility();
    blogService
      .create(newBlog)
      .then((returnedBlog) => {
        setBlogs(blogs.concat(returnedBlog));
        setNewBlog({
          title: "",
          content: "",
          author: "",
          url: "",
          likes: 0,
        });
        setSuccessMessage("BLOG A new blog added!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setErrorMessage(`BLOG Error: ${error.message}`);
        }, 5000);
      });
  };
```

The code works, but I want to write a test, and I cant figure out why its not working:

Test:

```
import React from 'react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import { BlogForm } from "../components/Form";
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

describe('Forms test' , () => { 

    test('submits new blog when save button is clicked' , async () => {
        const addBlogHandle = jest.fn()
        const handleBlogChange = jest.fn()
         // Mocking newBlog as an object
         const newBlog = {
            title: 'sdfdsf',
            content: 'sdfsdf',
            url: 'sdfdsf'
        }
        const user = userEvent.setup()

        render(<BlogForm
            addBlogHandle={addBlogHandle}
            handleBlogChange={handleBlogChange}
            newBlog={newBlog}
          />)

        const inputTitle = screen.getByPlaceholderText('title')
        const inputContent = screen.getByPlaceholderText('content')
        const inputUrl = screen.getByPlaceholderText('url')
        const submitButton = screen.getByText('save')
        


        user.type(inputTitle,"title")
        user.type(inputContent,"content")
        user.type(inputUrl,"url")
        user.click(submitButton)
        expect(addBlogHandle).toHaveBeenCalled();


        // The first test expectation ensures that submitting the form calls the addBlogHandle/ handleBlogChange method. 
        expect(addBlogHandle.mock.calls).toHaveLength(1)
        //expect(handleBlogChange.mock.calls).toHaveLength(1)

        //The second expectation checks that the event handler is called with the right parameters - 
        // that a note with the correct content is created when the form is filled.
        expect(addBlogHandle.mock.calls[0][0].content).toBe('content')

    })
```

I am testing a regular form component, Its props are two event functions, they are doing some api calls and changing the state of a Blog component. I cant figure out why this test is not working

```
ERROR:


expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0 
I cant figure out why
```

It seems that "save" button is not called ??